# Creating Java filter for image requests rewritings

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have created one filter which is working fine for all requests which my application gets, for this I have written new class `ResourceRequestWrapper` which extends `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to modify requests.

For example, when request comes for `/ui/tx/images/abc.png` I have overridden `getServletPath()`, `getRequestURL()` and `getRequestURI()` methods of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to modify text of incoming request to `/txeditor/images/abc.png`.

Now, I have created virtual directory in JBoss/Tomcat by modifying `server.xml` and adding following,

```
<Context path="/txeditor" docBase="C:\resources\web_resources\txeditor.war" unpackWAR="false">               
</Context>
```

I have also defined `WEB-INF` in `C:\resources\web_resources\txeditor.war` and created deployment descriptor as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
   <description>Web descriptor for the html adaptor</description> 
</web-app>
```

Everything above works fine, every request gets modified, but when my page gets opened I am not able to see any images and I think when we are modifying request from filter to access virtual directory defined in `server.xml`, its not possible?

Can anybody have other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed not going to work. You want to redirect the request instead.

```
String oldUrl = request.getRequestURI();
String newUrl = oldUrl.replaceFirst("/ui/tx/", "/txteditor/");
response.sendRedirect(newUrl);
```

If you want a permanent (301) redirect, do the following instead of the last line:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", newUrl);
```