# Basic questions about uploading files in JSF

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, uploading

I have never used uploading feature in JSF, but now I have to. I have couple of questions and they are like "for dummies" series questions. So:

1) Logged in users' pictures to DB or to filesystem of server?

2) If to server relative or fixed path or root url to db/properties and relative part to db too?

3) If to DB, how is the performance when using JPA2 + Mysql? Any cons otherwise?

4) If using server, is it secure to add new context for images to server.xml and use images from the address www.examble.com/imagesfolder/images.jpg? How to avoid the situation that everyone can see the pictures?

5) What is the best way to handle uploading? I am using Primefaces, is it good for that purpose or something else?

6) Any good tutorial or examples how to do this like a pro :)?

7) How to avoid situation that there might be files with a same name? Hashing the names or?

8) What if (really big if) I decide to share my application to two physical servers, problems with paths to pictures?

9) In my case, I have pictures, which are common to everyone and pictures "owned by logged in users. How would you implement this and why if you know that I am using Primefaces, JPA2 and Mysql and I have unlimited space in the server?

10) Very nice and hot summer to everyone!!

Sami

Answer (score 2):

Most of your questions are about what to do with the file once you have uploaded, that's a design matter and will depend on the software architect, the team leader or in last case on yourself. There are two good answers for the server filesystem/database file saving:

- [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751/1065197)
- [manage uploaded files in database or file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3707681/1065197)

To handle problems like described in "7)" and "8)", you should use a [file server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_server) and a Content Management systems. They also add more benefits than just file storage, as searching, indexing and more. Here are some examples:

- [The BarracudaDrive Web-File-Manager Plugin](https://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/WebFileManager.lsp)
- [Alfresco ECM](http://www.alfresco.com/products/features)

To implement file uploading using JSF (Note: to do it like a pro, follow the pros ways):

- [File upload using JSF 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html) by BalusC (JSF expert)
- [PrimeFaces Simple FileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf)

Give a try these samples. If you have a problem in your coding it would be better to ask a new question.

EDIT: I forgot of number 4, thanks for the reminder. I would add a new context, as you stated, and create a Filter that will catch the requests for this new context and will redirect to a default URL.

More on this issue:

- [The Essentials of Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)
- [How to use a filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2725102/1065197)
- [Creating Java filter for image requests rewritings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5755810/1065197)

Comment: What you think about number 4? Is there secure way to use "add new context"-method? I will read all of those and start to implement it today so maybe I will ask something more precise after that. Thanks! I think that I will use server instead of DB, there is couple of good reasons for that in my case.

Comment: @Sami sorry I forgot to tell you that I've updated my answer. Hope it resolves your questions :).